# Sprite kit project builds and runs on device but not simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, sprite-kit

I have a problem with xcode. I can create a project with the default templates such as single view application/empty application/spritekit game. All templates will build and work, except for spritekit.

Without making any changing to the default spritekit project it builds fine, but crashes with SIGABRT signal. It works fine when I build and run on my device. I have quit xcode/restarted mac but still get this error. I have downloaded sample spritekit projects and have the same error with them too.

Comment: Is there anything printed in the log/console besides SIGABRT?

Comment: Just (lldb) - Reverted to previous version of xcode and I still have the same problem...

Comment: Are you using an iOS 7 emulator? As far as I know Sprite Kit works only for iOS 7 and newer

Comment: Yup - using ios 7.1 emulator. Just updated to xcode 5.1 and it still persists. Having to use my device all the time now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared out temporary folders/resetting ios simulator and nothing worked - ended up having to remove xcode and reinstalling it.

Comment: I have also faced this same problem with SpritKit framework and resolved it by removing and reinstalling Xcode 8 beta. The problem might be like the SpritKit framework module removed in Swift bundle.